# Linked stacks and queues

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, stack, queue

Came across Linked Stacks and Queues in a book(and it is not stack/queue implementation using linked list).
it says that stack/queue can be represented sequentially if we had only one stack/queue.However, when several stacks/queues coexisted ,then there is no efficient way to represent them sequentially.
Below is the code given

```
#define MAX_STACKS 10 //maximum number of stacks;
typedef struct {
        int key;
        //other fields.
}element;
typedef struct stack *stackpointer;
typedef struct {
        element data;
        stackpointer link;
}stack;
stackpointer top[MAX_STACKS];

void push(int i ,element item) {
     stackpointer temp;
     malloc(temp,sizeof(*temp));
     temp->data = item;
     temp->link = top[i];
     top[i] = temp;
}
```

Am newbie to data structures. Can I get the brief explantion of above concept i.e Linked Stacks/Queues.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking here. Are you asking for an explanation of how to use a linked list to implement a stack or a queue?

Comment: It's actually stack implementation using linked list but how do you implement two or more stacks with linked list such that all stacks are linked .

Comment: What do you mean, "all stacks are linked?"

Comment: check the push() code , if u can understand what the concept is about

Comment: Your call to `malloc` is wrong. It should be `temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp))`. Your `push` is clear. I still don't know what you mean by "the stacks are linked."  It's difficult to understand what you're asking because we don't have the context of the book. You say, "there is no efficient way to represent them sequentially" is correct: you can't have multiple stacks in a single linked list, and still access them efficiently. Your comment "if u can understand what the concept is about" is rather condescending. The problem is that your question is unclear, not that I'm unintelligent.

Comment: am sorry ,but by that statement I didn't mean that you or other  are unintelligent. Its my problem that I couldn't convey to you what am asking for.

Comment: I cam across this code from a book with title **Fundamental Of Data Structures  with C**  by Horowitz , Sahni , Anderson-Freed .Check the context here - [link](http://apachetechnology.in/ati/www/KC/dw/Horowitz%20Sahni%20-%20Data%20Structure.pdf)  page no:118  @Jim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I checked out your book and I kind of understand what your problem is.

> Such a representation proved efficient if we had only one stack or one queue. However, when several stacks and queues co−exist, there was noefficient way to represent them sequentially

So, by sequential, you must understand that it means using arrays to represent stacks and not a linked list. Now just assume that you have a matrix comprising of 10 arrays to represent each of size 100, and you push some data into each. Say you push only a few elements in each stack, what happens is that you end up wasting a lot of data as there are a 1000 elements in the matrix. This problem was there while using a single array but it becomes more pronounced when you have multiple arrays for multiple stacks.

Now as you might have understood, using the linked list representation of a stack uses as much memory as needed, with only a slight overhead of keeping track of the next element, in this case stackpointer link.

`stackpointer top[MAX_STACKS]`

So what we  have done here is create an array of type stackpointer to keep track of the top position of each individual stack. So now whenever the user wishes to enter an element, they must pass the index(int i) as well as the data (element item).

```
void push(int i ,element item) 
{
     stackpointer temp;
     malloc(temp,sizeof(*temp));
     temp->data = item;
     temp->link = top[i];
     top[i] = temp;
}
```

So what we do is create a temp variable to store our data, which will now become the top of our stack but before doing so we must point it to the previous top of stack, (that is done in line 5) and in line 6, we just point the top[i] to temp.
However, you might want to correct your code with this

```
stackpointer temp = (stackpointer)malloc(sizeof(element));
```

If you have doubts, on malloc, just refer to [this](https://study.cs50.net/malloc).
If you have a doubt, let me know and I will clarify anything you need.

Comment: Thankyou . I understood the concept , but size of temp should be same as stackpointer because temp is a pointer variable of type stackpointer.   Stackpointer temp = (stackpointer)malloc(sizeof(stackpointer))  isn't it correct??

Comment: stackpointer is a pointer for element,if you use Stackpointer temp = (stackpointer)malloc(sizeof(stackpointer)) , then you are creating a pointer to a pointer which we don't want.

Comment: @PraveenParihar, hey mate, this is kind of an odd request, but I was banned from the site on answering questions. Could you help me out as an upvote might give me  a better chance to appeal said decision?